# Model is running iOS 10.2 (14C92), which may not be supported by this version of Xcode

Tags: xcode8, ios10, xcode10, ios12, ios11.3

I am facing this error, i am done with research on that.

I conclude the result, i need one file for device support 10.2(14C92)

Please share that file.

GoTo:

- Right click on Xcode 8 or Newer version of your Xcode, select "Show
  Package Contents", "Contents", "Developer", "Platforms",
  "iPhoneOS.Platform", "Device Support"
- Copy the **10.2(14C92)** folder (or above for later version).

I need that folder.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried downloading Xcode 8.2?

Comment: @AdamWright It is last option, i need only device support folder for 10.2(14C92).

Comment: @AdamWright is Xcode 8.2 available?  I'm on Xcode 8.1 and don't see an update for xcode.

Comment: It is. The Mac App Store can be painful; have you tried restarting?

Comment: I got this for Xcode 8.3.3 today. "This iPhone 7 Plus (Model 1661, 1784, 1785, 1786) is running iOS 10.3 (14E277), which may not be supported by this version of Xcode."

Comment: Do we have latest file that supports ios 14.0.1 ??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here I have this file for 12.1 or 12.0 or 11.3 or 11.4 into Xcode 8+ or XCode 9+. You can download file from this link. 10.3:- https://www.dropbox.com/s/i1f7q8w3vgr2ozl/10.3%20%2814E269%29.zip?dl=0

11.3:- https://www.dropbox.com/s/wya3eu2j5db7tpt/11.3%20%2815E217%29.zip?dl=0

11.4:- https://www.dropbox.com/s/86i9zjunpsy9b0b/11.4%20%2815F79%29.zip?dl=0

12.0 & 12.1:- https://github.com/Yatko/iOS-device-support-files

Steps:-

Download above Zip file and extract them.

1. Click on "Finder" in MAC OS
2. Click on "Go to Folder"
3. Paste this path over their (make sure that you have installed xcode with named : "Xcode.app") /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport
4. Paste your extracted "10.3 (14E269)" directory to that place.
5. quite Xcode and restart it. you can run your projects successfully in your real device.

**If you download the latest version after 12.1 then please upload that file and update the answer.**

Comment: If you download version after 12.1 then please upload that file and update answer.

Answer (score 15):

If somebody facing similar issue with Xcode 9.1
[image]

1. Open directory:

   **/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport**
2. Create new folder "11.2 (15C107)" (or "10.3 (14E269)" for older versions, depends on what exactly are you missing)
3. Paste files from provided google drive folder

   [11.2 (15C107)](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1c-hie8vJk7EQdRcZey6IK4P91KVIO8NQ)
   (or [10.3 (14E269)](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6RLdMSojh9TOW5DZmV1WVB3N3c) if you need older files)
4. Restart Xcode

For other iOS versions you may check @Sour LeangChhean 's answer

Keep in mind, that some day you will need to upgrade your Xcode anyway :)

Comment: @mramosch It's there, just in case :)

Comment: saved me 3 hours

Comment: Working like a charm, You save my whole day. :)

Answer (score 11):

I had the exactly same problem.
Just upgraded to xcode version 8.2.1 ( 8C1002 ) and the problem was solved.

Comment: Ohk , you have updated xcode right?? Then Please goto XCODE right click-> Show Package Contents-> Contents-> Developer-> Platforms-> iPhoneOS.Platform-> Device Support -> 10.2(14C92) Attach last folder any where please...

Comment: @PiyushSanepara You got files for 10.2 ? Even I'm searching for that. If then please share

Comment: @Nitesh i'm not getting that files but my problem solved. I ran application in 7.3.1 then i ran in 8.1 it works but i can't understand what actually doing behind that i checked Device support folder for both but i can't found it.

Comment: @Nitesh check this: https://www.dropbox.com/s/r6s0sc00i2avovo/10.2%20%2814C89%29.zip?dl=0

Comment: hi, do you have the latest version now ? could you please upload latest device support for 10.2 (14C92) and 10.2.1

Comment: Is there any image for 11.0.3 (15A432) ?

Answer (score 10):

Here I have this file for 10.3 or 11.3 or 11.4 into Xcode 8+.
You can download file from this link.
10.3:-
https://www.dropbox.com/s/i1f7q8w3vgr2ozl/10.3%20%2814E269%29.zip?dl=0

11.3:-
https://www.dropbox.com/s/wya3eu2j5db7tpt/11.3%20%2815E217%29.zip?dl=0

11.4:-
https://www.dropbox.com/s/86i9zjunpsy9b0b/11.4%20%2815F79%29.zip?dl=0

9 -> 12 All Files:
https://github.com/mendaparadarshit/xcode-9-ios-12-support

Steps:-

1. Download above Zip file and extract them.
2. Click on "Finder" in MAC OS, You can see in Topbar all menus, Click on "Go"
3. Click on "Go to Folder" ()
4. Paste this path over their (make sure that you have installed xcode with named : "Xcode.app")
   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport
5. Paste your extracted "10.3 (14E269)" directory to that place.
6. quite Xcode and restart it. you can run your projects successfully in your real device.

Thank you,

Darshit

Comment: Any chance to get 11.2 onto your dropbox/GoogleDrive? Thx in advance...

Comment: Can you add ios 12 simulator ?

Answer (score 4):

I downloaded the appropriate zip file from https://github.com/iGhibli/iOS-DeviceSupport/tree/master/DeviceSupport for my devices version of iOS

Unzipped the contained folder to

> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport

And finally restarted Xcode. No need to update Xcode it's self

Answer (score 2):

Here is steps to build on device with iOS 10.3 and Xcode 8.2.1:

1. Open next  directory: `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport`
2. Create new folder "10.3 (14E277)"
3. Copy files: `DeveloperDiskImage.dmg`, `DeveloperDiskImage.dmg.signature` FROM 10.2 (14C89) folder TO new 10.3 (14E277)
4. Restart Xcode

[image]

Comment: well it throws 'An error was encountered while enabling development on this device. please try rebooting and reconnecting the device (0xE8000076)'. Tried rebooting and searching SO for this error, but didn't find anything useful. So any help here?

Comment: thats interesting.. do you have version 14E277 on device?

Comment: I had the same error. Contents from 10.3 folder of Xcode 8.3 solved it.

Answer (score 2):

I solved the problem by updating Xcode.

However, for some strange reason the update was NOT shown in App Store under the Updates section. I had to manually search App Store for Xcode and select GET, then INSTALL. It installed a newer version, and problem was solved.

Not sure why Apple does this to developers ...

Answer (score 1):

I have this problem, and I solved this by downloading the latest Xcode version.

Answer (score 1):

you need update your xCode to the last current version.
Each version have the last iOS version included.

Answer (score -2):

Try register your device in the provisioning profile using its UDID.