# Xcode not supported for iOS 11.2.1 by Xcode 9.1 needed 9.2

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, xcode9.2

I get the following error. I have Xcode 9.1. I was searching for 9.2 which not available yet at App store.

> This iPhone 7 Plus (Model 1661, 1784, 1785, 1786) is running iOS 11.2.1 (15C153), which may not be supported by this version of Xcode 9.1 and I need 9.2...

Comment: Xcode 9.2 is availbale in the AppStore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally Found link from where I got xCode 9.2

https://developer.apple.com/download/more/

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In order to save some time you also may just add missing folder to your current version of Xcode. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/43098731/4820235